# Read EXIF online without need to upload photos

Tags: html, exif

I have an HTML5 site. I want to do following thing:

1. Walk through files in a folder
2. Find all images
3. Get exif file from images
4. Analyze an exifs (on server)
5. Correct bad exifs

This is a best scenario, that it can be. I am conscious that 1st and 2second step is possibly done only by selecting this files by user. And 5th step is possible only when the analysis will be done at user's machine. So what is the best way to do it (to get closer as much to the optimal scenario)? What should I use without need to force a user to install anything?

EDIT:
At least I have used free GeckoFX web browser as a basic desktop app. Interface is created in HTML+JS Thx all

Comment: to view EXIF i use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3905/

Comment: I know that much of this things are possibly done using Flex or Silverlight. But I want to do it without these two technologies. So some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an application that runs on the computer of the user. You can't create an HTML5 site that does this.

Answer (score 0):

A Chrome HTML5 webapp should be able to do this.
I'm actually looking at this in these days.

Here is a NOT WORKING example ( due to old API specs, I think)
http://benno.id.au/blog/2009/12/30/html5-fileapi-jpegmeta

But should at least give some good insights.

Answer (score -1):

You should use ExifTool.
It is available as a Perl library here:
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ExifTool.html
And also as a command-line tool which can be ran by the server (same site).